# how to use properly variable ARRAY<STRUCT<>>

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to store the result set into an array of structs, but it doesn’t work as I expected. Maybe someone knows what is wrong. I do not have any error messages.

```
declare rs ARRAY<STRUCT<created_date TIMESTAMP, unique_key STRING, complaint_description STRING>>;

SET rs = 
(
    ARRAY (
            SELECT AS STRUCT created_date, unique_key, complaint_description
            FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_311.311_service_requests`
            LIMIT 10
          )
);

select * from unnest(rs);
```

Comment: works perfectly for me! so what you mean by `it doesn’t work as I expected`? what is wrong you think?

Comment: Data Set Configuration Error

Data Studio cannot connect to your data set.

Failed to fetch data from the underlying data set

Error ID: 42fd2208

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.